# Running Some Code Multiple Times Asynchronously With Different Variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, healthkit, hksamplequery

So, I am trying to get my app to read in `HealthKit` data. I have a function that I call from the main app view controller which causes a query in another class for all the health data in that month. Theres then a few calculations before the array of data is returned from a separate function in the calculation class, to a separate function in the view controller.

The queries take around 2 seconds each due to the volume of data. I would like to be able to set them off asynchronously and when they have all returned, I can update the UI.

The problem is, I call the function for each month, which goes and starts the `HKSampleQueries`, but they don't return in order, and the time that it takes for them to return varies. This means that I end up with variables being changed halfway through one set of datas calculations because the next set has just started.

I only know two ways round this:

Set a delay before calling each calculation like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}
```

But that wastes app time

Or I could just duplicate the code several times and call different class for each month. But that seems stupid and inefficient.

So question is. How do I effectively share code that will run several times with different variables each time.
Cheers

Example of function:

**In View controller:**

```
HeartRateCalculator *commonClassTwo =[[HeartRateCalculator alloc] init];
[commonClassTwo calculateData:0];
[commonClassTwo calculateData:-1];
[commonClassTwo calculateData:-2];
```

**In HeartRateCalculator**

```
-(void)calculateData:(NSInteger)monthsBack{
  //Some other stuff
//Generate monthPeriodPredicate based on monthsBack integer
  HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:heartRate predicate:monthPeriodPredicate limit:200000 sortDescriptors:@[timeSortDescriptor] resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
  //Finish Calculations, call other functions (ie. [self doThis];) and then return
//When calculations return, monthPeriodPredicate is always value of the last predicate to be called, not the one that the HKSampleQuery was made with.
}
[healthStoreFive executeQuery:query];
```

Full Code:

```
-(void)calculateData:(NSInteger)monthsBack withCompletionBlock:(void(^)())completionBlock {//0 Means only current month, 2 means this month and last month and month before
//for(NSInteger i=0; i>=monthsBack; i--){
    //monthForCalculation = monthsBack;
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateComponents *adjustableComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [adjustableComponent setMonth:monthsBack];
    [adjustableComponent setDay:-[components day]+1];
    [adjustableComponent setHour:-[components hour]];
    [adjustableComponent setMinute:-[components minute]];
    [adjustableComponent setSecond:-[components second]];
    startOfMonth = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:adjustableComponent toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
    adjustableComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [adjustableComponent setMonth:1];
    NSDate *endOfMonth = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:adjustableComponent toDate:startOfMonth options:0];

    NSDate *secondEarlier = [endOfMonth dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1];
    components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:secondEarlier];
    daysInMonth = [components day];

    NSPredicate *monthPeriodPredicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startOfMonth endDate:endOfMonth options:HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate];
    healthStoreFive = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];
    HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];
    NSSortDescriptor *timeSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate ascending:NO];
    HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:heartRate predicate:monthPeriodPredicate limit:200000 sortDescriptors:@[timeSortDescriptor] resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        NSMutableArray *dataValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *dataDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (HKQuantitySample *sample in results) {
            [dataValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[sample.quantity doubleValueForUnit:[[HKUnit countUnit] unitDividedByUnit:[HKUnit minuteUnit]]]]];
            [dataDates addObject:sample.startDate];
        }
        monthForCalculation = monthsBack;
        chronologicalDataValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        chronologicalDataDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        chronologicalDataValues = [[[dataValues reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];
        chronologicalDataDates = [[[dataDates reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];          
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(dataDates.count == 0){
                ViewController *commonClass =[[ViewController alloc] init];
                [commonClass receiveCalculationData:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] array:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] daysToDisplay:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] chosenMonth:monthForCalculation];
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"%@", [dataDates objectAtIndex:dataDates.count-1]);
                NSLog(@"%@", [dataDates objectAtIndex:0]);
                [self calculateDayStringsFromData];
            }

            completionBlock();
        //});
    }];
    NSLog(@"HKSampleQuery Requested For Heart Rate Data");
    [healthStoreFive executeQuery:query];
```

// }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dispatch_group` in order to schedule a block to fire after all of your tasks are completed.

You just have to modify your `calculateData:` method to accept a `dispatch_group_t` argument (you can always add a completion block as well if needed):

```
- (void)calculateData:(NSInteger)monthsBack group:(dispatch_group_t)group {

    dispatch_group_enter(group); // increment group task count

    //Some other stuff

    HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:heartRate predicate:monthPeriodPredicate limit:200000 sortDescriptors:@[timeSortDescriptor] resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {

        //Finish Calculations, call other functions (ie. [self doThis];) and then return

        dispatch_group_leave(group); // decrement task count
    }];

    [healthStoreFive executeQuery:query];

}
```

Then you can just call it like so:

```
HeartRateCalculator *commonClassTwo =[[HeartRateCalculator alloc] init];

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

[commonClassTwo calculateData:0 group:group];
[commonClassTwo calculateData:-1 group:group];
[commonClassTwo calculateData:-2 group:group];

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // called when all tasks are finished.
    // update UI
});
```

It's the same principle that [Warif was going for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432246/2976878), but `dispatch_groups` are *much* more elegant than using your own variable to track the number of tasks executing.

---

Although I'm not sure what you mean when you say that you want the tasks to be asynchronously executed. From the [Apple docs on `HKSampleQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKSampleQuery_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKSampleQuery/initWithSampleType:predicate:limit:sortDescriptors:resultsHandler:):

> Queries run on an anonymous background queue.

Therefore your tasks are *already* asynchronous.

Comment: So, sorry to report but Im still not having much luck here. Im finding that all the HKSampleQueries return in order, but a variable that I generate just before the query (specifically the start date for the predicate) is changed each time before the query returns. I am then unable to use it in subsequent calculations. Any Ideas?

Comment: @SimonEdwardes where are you defining the `monthPeriodPredicate`? Please add the full code to the OP

Comment: Ill try and add the full code now, sorry Ive only commented it for now

Comment: @SimonEdwardes where is `startOfMonth` defined? it looks like it could be an instance variable, therefore it'll be changed every time you make a query.

Comment: @SimonEdwardes if you need instance variables to be independent for each query, then you should be creating a new object for each one, like [Jeremiah suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35436360/2976878).

Comment: Cheers guys, got there in the end. the `startOfMonth` variable was declared at the top for the whole class, I changed that and then just handed it through the odd function and all was well. Love `dispatch_group` btw!

Comment: So I'm having a problem with a crash, and I'm using the dispatch_group method above. Any suggestions. I guess somethings being deallocated too early but not sure....  `4   *AppName* 0x00000001000c6ab4 __destroy_helper_block_ + 24 (HeartRateCalculator.m:0)
5   libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x00000001823098e8 _Block_release + 156 (runtime.c:312)
6   HealthKit                      0x0000000190b7279c __destroy_helper_block_ + 24 (HKSampleQuery.m:59)`

Comment: @SimonEdwardes I would suggest asking a new question about this – without the full details it's almost impossible to know what's wrong. You can always link back to this question if you feel it would help provide context.

Answer (score 2):

Use `block`

```
[commonClassTwo calculateData:0 withCompletionBlock:^{
    [commonClassTwo calculateData:-1 withCompletionBlock:^{
        [commonClassTwo calculateData:-2 withCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"All 3 calculation done");
        }];
    }];
}];
```

---

```
- (void)calculateData:(NSInteger)monthsBack withCompletionBlock:(void(^)())completionBlock {
    //Some other stuff
    HKSampleQuery *query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:heartRate predicate:monthPeriodPredicate limit:200000 sortDescriptors:@[timeSortDescriptor] resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        //Finish Calculations, call other functions (ie. [self doThis];) and then return
        completionBlock();
    }
    [healthStoreFive executeQuery:query];
}
```

---

**Update**

For async call, have a counter an `integer`. Initial value will be the number of async calls you want to have. (here 3) 
In the completionBlock of each call, decrement the counter and check if all calls are completed or not.
if completed update the `UI`.

```
[commonClassTwo calculateData:0 withCompletionBlock:^{
    // counter--;
    // [self updateUI];
}];

[commonClassTwo calculateData:-1 withCompletionBlock:^{
    // counter--;
    // [self updateUI];
}];

[commonClassTwo calculateData:-2 withCompletionBlock:^{
    // counter--;
    // [self updateUI];
}];
```

```
- (void)updateUI {
    // if counter == 0 {
    //     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //         update UI
    //     });
    // }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Works great, the only thing is that its a bit slow. How would I run these simultaneously? Because if I'm right then at the moment it is doing one and finishing before doing the next? cheers

Comment: quote from question: `I would like to be able to set them off synchronously and when they have all returned, I can update the UI.` Your previous code was doing it simultaneously. please clarify.

Comment: @SimonEdwardes **off topic:** you have never accepted any of your questions. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: Sorry, Ill edit the question, I only thought asynchronous now because I was hoping running them in parallels would improve speed, Cheers

Comment: also worth noting that when you update the UI, you should be dispatching onto the main queue first. The `HKSampleQuery` completion block is called on a background queue - and UI updates should always take place on the main queue.

Comment: @originaluser2 is right. UI update should always be on main queue. answer edited with `dispatch_async`. `dispatch_group` looks very interesting. Im checking on it. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can make seperate classes instead and run them all at the same time.

```
HeartRateCalculator *commonClassOne =[[HeartRateCalculator alloc] init];
HeartRateCalculator *commonClassTwo =[[HeartRateCalculator alloc] init];
HeartRateCalculator *commonClassThree =[[HeartRateCalculator alloc] init];
[commonClassOne calculateData:0];
[commonClassTwo calculateData:-1];
[commonClassThree calculateData:-2];
```

This way you don't have to duplicate the code but they won't overwrite values in the same class.